# how to change the value of one signal in two different processes? in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to do a state machine for different protocols that link together, each protocol has its own process in VHDL. I want to assign '1' to one signal and in the other process I should assign '0'. For example in the first process when I assign '1' it starts writing and in the second process when I assign '0' it stops writing.

I tried different things but nothing is working. I keep getting this error

```
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net at
```

is there a way that I can work around this issue?

The code for the first when `wb_do_write <= '1';` assign to '1' and it starts writing the data from one protocol to another is

this is the first process

```
elsif (ss_reg(2 downto 1)="01")   then    -- device is deactivated
  --  MISO <= 'Z';
        o_data <= shift_reg;   -- save the recieved byte when transmision ends
        wb_do_write <= '1';
    
        o_data_valid <= '1';
   
      end if;
```

the code where `wb_do_write <= '1';` should be assigned back to zero so it stops writing is

this is the second process

```
WHEN WB_WRITE =>
            IF wb_ack_i = '1' THEN
              wb_complete <= '1';
              wb_stb_o    <= '0';
              wb_cyc_o    <= '0';
            --wb_do_write <= '0' ; here is the problem, I can't assign this signal again to '0'
              wb_state <= WB_FINISH;
            END IF;
```

Comment: You cannot drive a signal from multiple processes. Each process "drives" the signal. So what happens when one process "drives" a '1', and the other drives '0' ? For a single signal, you can only drive it from a single process. You need to use this signal as a flag for the 2nd process to generate a 2nd signal.

Comment: It is not possible to implement such multi drive signals, as Tricky also comments.  An alternative is to make a start and stop signal for each process, and then pulse these for one cycle if either of the processes want to start or stop the write.  Then make a third process that combines the start and stop indications from the processes, with proper choice of priority if both start and stop is indicated at the same time.

Comment: *I tried different things but nothing is working.* isn't an explicit problem statement. The error message describes an Altera/Intel hardware synthesis limitation you're trying to patch around. There are 21 questions here with the same error message, 9 have accepted answers. Without enough detail your question cannot be differentiated from them nor made clear enough to your readers to be answered comprehensively. See [ask].

Comment: It IS possible ... but inadvisable. One approach is for both processes to drive "Z" on that signal when they don't actively require to drive it; this enables the other to access it. Of course you need arbitration so they don't both claim it at once, and you must cover the case where neither drives it, but there are standard approaches to that.  This doesn't work internally in most FPGAs from this century, but synthesis can usually translate it to something that does.  Another approach is to research "Wired OR" logic. Both widely covered here and elsewhere; do some research.

Comment: @Tricky and @Morten: it is indeed possible. Multiple drive situations are perfectly valid if you use a resolved type (e.g., `std_logic`) and your target technology supports it (tri-state buffers) or if your synthesizer is able to convert it into supported multiplexed logic. Frequently the problem is not multiple drive situations, it is **unwanted** multiple drive situations or **not understanding** what it is and what the corresponding hardware is. Here we are probably in the **not understanding** case.

Comment: @Sameh: What you probably did not completely understand is that when you write `s <= '1'` in a process you are modelling an active piece of hardware that will continuously maintain this driving value until the **same process** assigns another value to signal `s`. So, if you do this from two different processes you are modelling two pieces of hardware that will continuously maintain their driving values. This has a name: **short-circuit** (except if you use tri-state buffers and the `Z`, `H`, `L` or `W` values of type `std_logic`).